# confusion about Einstein notation

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I have the following expression

$$
\partial_k\sigma_{ik} = \partial_i\partial_ku_k + \partial_k^2u_i
$$

I know that a repeated index means summation. So for a 2D space $(x, y)$ I would get (for the first equation, $i=x$)

$$
\partial_x\sigma_{xx} + \partial_y\sigma_{xy}= \partial_x\partial_xu_x + \partial_x\partial_yu_y + \partial_k^2u_i
$$
But what does the last term become?

Comment: Seems to me like non-standard notation, but: since the result should not depend on $k$, you're right that *something* should happen. If you write $\partial^2_k = \partial_k \partial_k$ then you have your repeated index. If in doubt that this is what is meant, perhaps you have a simple example you could check it against?

Comment: $\partial_k^2 = \partial_x^2 + \partial_y^2$, the Laplacian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the two equations you get are

\begin{align*}
\partial_x\sigma_{xx} + \partial_y\sigma_{xy} &= \partial_x\partial_xu_x + \partial_x\partial_yu_y + \partial_x^2u_x + \partial_y^2u_x,\ \text{and}\\
\\
\partial_x\sigma_{yx} + \partial_y\sigma_{yy} &= \partial_y\partial_xu_x + \partial_y\partial_yu_y + \partial_x^2u_y + \partial_y^2u_y.
\end{align*}